# Fullscreen Electron application on startup

Tags: vue.js, electron, fullscreen, yarnpkg

I have created an application with Vue and Node in Electron. I run the application using command `yarn run electron:serve`. How can I get this application to start in full screen mode? Consider that even when the application is built, I want it to start it in full screen when `.exe` file is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use .maximize() on the main process. You can add conditions if you only want to use it in prod